# change prototype script to jquery one

Tags: jquery, forms, prototypejs

I have this form submit code:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', init, false);
function init() {
  Event.observe('addressForm', 'submit', storeAddress);
}
function storeAddress(e) {
  $('response').innerHTML = 'Adding email address...';
  var pars = 'address=' + escape($F('address'));
  var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('response', 'ajaxServer.php', {method: 'get', parameters: pars});
  Event.stop(e);
}
```

How can I change it to work with jQuery?

Here is the html form:

> ```
> <form id="addressForm" action="index.php" method="get">
>   <b>Email:</b> <input type="text"  name="address" id="address" size="25"><br>
>   <input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
>   <p id="response"><?php echo(storeAddress()); ?></p>
> </form>
> ```

and this is php code at start of document:

```
<?php
require_once("inc/storeAddress.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#addressForm').submit(function() {
        $('#response')
            .html('Adding email address...')
            .load('ajaxServer.php', { address: $('#address').val() }, function() {
                $('#address').val('');
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note: when using `.load()`, the POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed. So, if you want to pass the data as GET, use:

```
.load('ajaxServer.php', 'address='+$('#address').val());
```

Or just get the submitted data from `$_POST['address']` which would be wiser and easier in my opinion.

Comment: hi this is not submitting data

Comment: can you do one more help, how can i clear the email field once the request is submitted.
thanks

Comment: @steve - Change the `.load(...` line to this: `.load('ajaxServer.php', { address: $('#address').val() }, function() { $('#address').val(''); });`

Comment: @steve, just as Nick Craver said. I added it in my example for clarity.

Comment: thanks, one last question...when i move my ajaxServer.php to a child directory (/email) and i change path  .load('ajaxServer.php..... to .load('email/ajaxServer.php...i get error... do i need to change more?

Comment: just to clearify..... if i remove the script from page, the data will submit but with page refresh ofcourse...i.e i have set all other paths correct once i move into child directory, i think i need some change in this java script only. thanks

Comment: oh sorry my mistake...working all fine now

great support
   
thanks a lot   
Tatu Ulmanen,  Nick Craver and John Himmelman for your precious time

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the script like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#addressForm').submit(function(e) {
    $('#response').html('Adding email address...');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxServer.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'address': $('#address').val() },
        success: function(response) {
          $('#response').html(response);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });​
});
```

Here's a rundown of the equivalents:

- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for the innerHTML call
- [`$('#id')` selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for finding by an ID
- [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the ajax call

  - `data` is the passed parameters, set the pair up (address=...)
  - `success` callback runs when the request completes

    - put the response into the `id="response"` div here

Comment: although data is submitted but page is reloading aswell

Comment: @steve - Updated, this should prevent the default submit from happening now.

Comment: You would be better off observing the submit event on the form rather then the click event on the submit button. Looks like that's what the prototype code was doing too.

Comment: @ Nick Craver thanks for you time looking into this, actually i am trying to submit form with out page refresh...the updated version isnt doing that still..
is there i am missing? somr thing you need to know from my side? do let me know

Comment: @petersendidit can you kindly let me know what to chnage...i am a mess with codes :( and i need this one working soon,,,thanks

Comment: @steve, @petersendidit - Updated one more time, I'm basing this off you using jQuery 1.4 and the submit handler normalized (even in IE).  Try the updated answer again, if there are still problems, it's most likely a javascript error being thrown, and a link to a page I can see would be helpful.

Comment: still problem :( i actually dont have a page set for web preview, i am testing this on my local server, i will however provide you one link in few hours

thanks for your time
i am grateful

Comment: @steve - Something I take for granted most times, were you wrapping this in a `$(function() { });` like I added above?  If not please do.

Comment: i am actually copying your whole code
.pasting it in a java file that i call in page.

Comment: @steve - Then do that once more, should work, sorry I forgot the obvious.

Comment: hi, sorry but still no luck, data submits but still with page refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a whirl..

```
function init()
{
    $('#addressForm').submit(storeAddress);
}

function storeAddress(e)
{
    $('#response').html('Adding address...');

    var params = 'address=' + $('#address').val();

    $('#response').load('ajaxServer.php', params);

    $.ajax({
        url : 'index.php',
        data : $('#addressForm').serialize(),
        success : function(data)
        {
            alert('yay, form data sent!');
        }
    });

    // Fix - stops page reload
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

Comment: i was trying that page wont reload, although data is submitted but page is reloading aswell

Comment: Try now, it sends the form data ajaxically and stops the form from submitting (by returning false).

Comment: oh yes it works 
sweet
how will i remove the alert window that pops up. i dont need that, also is this submitting data twice, emails are appearing in pairs with single submit.
thanks

Comment: Tatu: The first request fetches the status, the second submits the form data (form action is index.php).